# SQL Server T-SQL not returning results with no error - this should work right?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find something that does not match in 2 tables, this should be easy, now this works fine.

```
Select * 
from Shop_Import SI
where SI.productID not in (SELECT productref FROM Shop_Import_Cats)
```

But this is the SQL I need to use, but it just does not return the 1 result that the above does:

```
SELECT    
   'Insert into Shop_Import_Cats values ('
   + CAST(p.ProductID AS VARCHAR) + ','
   + CAST(c.CategoryID AS VARCHAR) + ','
   + CAST(SI.ProductID AS VARCHAR) + ',getdate())
FROM       
   NB_Store_Products p
JOIN 
   NB_Store_ProductLang pl ON p.ProductID = pl.ProductID
JOIN 
   Shop_Import SI ON p.ProductRef = SI.ProductID
JOIN 
   NB_Store_CategoryLang CL ON SI.Primary_Category = CL.CategoryName
JOIN 
   NB_Store_Categories C ON CL.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
JOIN 
   Shop_Import_Cats SIC ON SI.ProductID = SIC.productref
WHERE      
   SI.ProductID NOT IN (SELECT SIC.productref
                        FROM Shop_Import_Cats SIC)
```

Based on advice here I tried this swapping the tables around and left joins to no avail - it returns null but should return one result.

```
  Select 'Insert into Shop_Import_Cats values (' + CAST(p.ProductID as varchar) + ',' + CAST(c.CategoryID as varchar) + ',' + CAST(SI.ProductID as varchar) + ',getdate())'
   from Shop_Import SI 
    left join NB_Store_Products P on SI.ProductID=p.ProductRef
    left join NB_Store_ProductLang pl on p.ProductID=pl.ProductID
    left join NB_Store_CategoryLang CL on SI.Primary_Category=CL.CategoryName
    left join NB_Store_Categories C on CL.CategoryID=C.CategoryID
    left join Shop_Import_Cats SIC on SI.ProductID=SIC.productref
    where SI.ProductID not in (SELECT SIC.productref FROM Shop_Import_Cats SIC)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Inner Joins will filter your data. So if there is not a corresponding record in at least one of the tables used in the joins, then you won't get the record.

Comment: I did not know that, what kind of join would be best here in this case?

Comment: I would start from your main table, which seems to be `Shop_Import` in your case and then build up the joins using `LEFT JOIN`. Left Join will get all rows from the left table no matter if they exist on the right.

Comment: Yeah I did this before also while it came back with a NULL rather then the expected result.

Comment: No errors at all just no results if I say IN rather then NOT IN then I get a bunch of results, but i must use not in or != etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT    
   'Insert into Shop_Import_Cats values ('
   + CAST(coalesce(p.ProductID,' ') AS VARCHAR) + ','
   + CAST(coalesce(c.CategoryID,' ') AS VARCHAR) + ','
   + CAST(coalesce(SI.ProductID,' ') AS VARCHAR) + ',getdate())
   from (
       select 
           ProductID,
           Primary_Category 
           /* insert any additional required columnx here */
       from Shop_Import SI
       where SI.ProductID not in (SELECT SIC.productref FROM Shop_Import_Cats SIC)
   ) SI 
    left join NB_Store_Products P      on SI.ProductID        = p.ProductRef
    left join NB_Store_ProductLang pl  on p.ProductID         = pl.ProductID
    left join NB_Store_CategoryLang CL on SI.Primary_Category = CL.CategoryName
    left join NB_Store_Categories C    on CL.CategoryID       = C.CategoryID
    left join Shop_Import_Cats SIC     on SI.ProductID        = SIC.productref
```

Now the WHERE condition will be executed on the same *relvar* as in the working example. I suspect that a null value is invoking 3-valued logic and propagating an UNKNOWN into a null record-set.

** edit Needed to add the SI to the 'from Shop_Import'

Comment: Perfect - just made an edit on the from Shop_Import - thanks a billion for this, you have saved hours of stress.

Comment: @user2034164: Note that as you originally constructed the query, the WHERE was being applied **after** all the joins. Moving it to a subquery causes it to be applied **before** all the joins, so it works just as in your test case. I also `coalesced` all the possible NULLS from the joins to prevent 3-valued logic being invoked in the construction of the dynamic-SQL.

Comment: I believe returning no results has to do with the concatenation of `NULL` values. If one value in the concatenation is `NULL`, SQL returns `NULL` for the whole string, no matter what values are in the other parts.

Comment: @user2034164: To *really* save on stress, develop the habit of writing your queries like this from the get-go: *Criteria* applied at the right time, and all possible NULL values coalesced prior to being used.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens The problem with this is that it's generating an insert statement that is populating the target table with  ' ' instead of NULL values. To keep consistency with the three-valued logic, the coalesce should evaluate NULL values to the string 'NULL'.

Comment: @Jayvee: That's not necessarily true - the column might be non-nullable with some other default value that actually resides in the domain (to help avoid issues such as these); I do this all the time to minimize occurrence of stored NULLs in my DB's. Only a Domain expert (ie OP) can say which is correct in this instance.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens - what i mean is that the coalesce is artificially creating an id ' ' to circumvent the evaluation of the whole concatenation to NULL when the actual value is NULL. Using the string 'NULL' to replace the NULL value in the concatenation will end up inserting the value NULL in the target table, which is the true FK id value for the record being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove Shop_import_cats from the join:

```
  Select 'Insert into Shop_Import_Cats values (' + CAST(p.ProductID as varchar) + ',' + CAST(c.CategoryID as varchar) + ',' + CAST(SI.ProductID as varchar) + ',getdate())'
   from Shop_Import SI 
    left join NB_Store_Products P on SI.ProductID=p.ProductRef
    left join NB_Store_ProductLang pl on p.ProductID=pl.ProductID
    left join NB_Store_CategoryLang CL on SI.Primary_Category=CL.CategoryName
    left join NB_Store_Categories C on CL.CategoryID=C.CategoryID
    where SI.ProductID not in (SELECT SIC.productref FROM Shop_Import_Cats SIC)
```

Comment: Thats a good point its redundant, but even doing this does not work as does adding left joins to the above, 0 results, there is 1 result that is not a match

Comment: is more than redundant, it is contradiction; if it's "not in" then it will not join.

Comment: I've edited to include left joins and removing the shop_import_cats from the join. How does this work?

Comment: It returns a single Null - so I think its reconsigned there is one entry but not outputting what I expect for the result the way the simple query does at the very top of my original post does.

Comment: @user2034164 The problem is that if either p.oroduct or c.categoryID or si.productID are null then the whole expression will be null. You may need to use isnull surrounding each of them with empty string or the word 'NULL'.